# Sigma Notation.

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$\sum_{r=1}^n a_r=\frac {n}{4}(n+1)$$

This is a sum from my textbook that requires me to find the value of $a_3$.

I am not sure whether I understand this correctly, and it seems to me the equation will result like this:
$$\sum_{r=1}^n a_3=\frac {n}{4}(n+1)$$
$$=\frac 1 4(1+1) + \frac 2 4 (2+1) + \frac 3 4(3+1)$$
resulting in:
$$\frac 2 4 + \frac 6 4  + \frac {12} 4$$
$$=5$$

I drew this conclusion because I believe I can subsititute the initial "$r$" value from the equation to the value of "3," but I still have to perform the calculation where "$r=1$" to "$r=3$" in the equation.

Please could you affirm whether my conclusions and my understanding is correct? Thank you.

Comment: $\sum_{r=1}^n a_r=a_1+a_2+a_3+\cdots+a_n$

Comment: $$a_3 = (a_1 + a_2 + a_3) - (a_1 + a_2) = \Biggl(\sum_{r = 1}^3 a_r\Biggr)  - \Biggl(\sum_{r = 1}^2 a_r\Biggr)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach:

Take difference of terms on both sides:

$$a_r=\frac {r(r+1)}4-\frac {(r-1)r}4=\frac r2$$
Hence $$\color{red}{a_3=\frac 32}$$.

Comment: Hi! I don't think I quite get what you did here. Would you please explain in further detail? Thanks :)

Comment: In simple terms, summation and difference are two opposite operations. One adds consecutive terms, the other subtracts (takes the difference of) consecutive terms. This is similar to integration and differentiation. For LHS, taking he difference of a summation negates the summation operation leaving you with the original term. For RHS the difference of the $r$-th term, you take the $r$-th term subtract the $(r-1)$-th term. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

$$
\sum^{n}_{r=1} a_r = a_1 + a_2+ \cdots + a_n
$$

Thus $\sum^{n}_{r=1} a_r$ is just the sum of the first $n$ terms of a sequence $a_i$. Since we know that $a_3 = a_1 + a_2 + a_3 - a_1 - a_2$.

$$
\begin{align*}
a_3 &= \sum^{3}_{r=1} a_i - \sum^{2}_{r=1} a_i\\
&= \frac{3(3+1)}{4} - \frac{2(2+1)}{4}\\
&= \frac{12}{4} - \frac{6}{4} \\
&= \frac{6}{4}\\
\end{align*}
$$

Sidenote: $\sum^{n}_{r=1} a_3 = na_3$ and not $\frac{n(n+1)}{4}$